# MQ monitoring and integrating with google-analytics?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-analytics, ibm-mq

Here is the scenario. We have different environments which applications are hosted on. These applications access data or talk with other applications hosted on different environments.

We are using `mq message` for communication but there is no mechanism to track this communication activity.

Is it possible to monitor `mq message` with `google-analytcs`? If yes, would it be a good idea. Or is there a better solution?

**Update**:

Is there anyone has tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqlight and possible to integrate with `google-analytcs` ???

The idea is to built MQ monitoring dashboard (visualization, alerts, message details, source/destination details etc..) or integrate an event with `google-analytics` to track with MQ REST API.

I am a Javascript Developer and want to built such utility by consuming REST API with use of `angularjs` and `nodejs`.

**Is there any MQ REST API that can be used to built such utility ???**

Comment: *"...there is no mechanism to track this communication activity. "* What? Look [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools.html#mqmon) or [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html#mqadmin) for a selection of monitoring tools. Or use the instrumentation built into IBM MQ.  Or write your own exits. Also, are you aware that IBM MQ Light and IBM MQ are different protocols? Finally, question is too broad and opinion-based per [SO guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Voting to put on hold pending revision to make it more specific and on-topic.

Comment: @T.Rob- I've updated the question. Could you please help me out with that ???

Comment: I don't think the question is salvageable as a "programming question with a definitive answer" as per SO guidelines.  MQ doesn't have a native REST API.  Since what you appear to need here is a forum instead of Stack Overflow's narrow focus on "questions with code samples" I'd suggest http://mqseries.net would be the right place to ask.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm usually the guy arguing for relaxing rules and not the one voting to close. However, this one seems to have gone out of its way to break *every* possible item in the guidelines about [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). It's a great discussion question in any of the MQ forums, but way too broad and opinion-oriented for SO. The only reason it hasn't been closed is that we get such low traffic in the tag and I stopped short of flagging it for a mod - giving time for someone else to answer.